# VSCode custom font ligatures, display two symbols as one?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to display `list.emptyqm()` as `list.empty?()` in function names for specific language. So, two symbols `qm` if they are at the end of the function name should be displayed as `?` (possibly some unicode symbol looking similar to question mark).

Is that possible in VSCode?

The VSCode already knows that piece of text is string, or function-name/keyword/variable-name (as it highlights it properly), so the ligature should be displayed only if `qm` are the last
characters of function-name/keyword/variable-name. It shouldn't be displayed in the middle of the function name, like `aqma()` shouldn't be displayed as `a?a()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom font ligatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65189559/custom-font-ligatures)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misunderstand what a ligature is. A ligature describes how two individual letters can be combined to form a visual pleasing appearance. A ligature never changes the syntax of a text. Hence, converting `qm` to `?` is a completely different thing.

Replacing text in vscode is of course possible, for instance as part of the format command. You can register your own formatter and determine the text edit actions that you want to be applied, including the transformation of these character sequences.

Comment: Thanks, I probably not clearly explained, will update the question, but I don't want to replace `qm` with `?`. I only want it to be displayed as `?`, but the text itself should stay with `qm`. I need to change only how it's displayed for more pleasing visual appearance.

Comment: Ugh, I don't think that's possible. The editor cannot show different text than what's in its text model (which is the ultimate source of the editor content).

Comment: Maybe it is possible, but for this, you have to create your own font, with its own ligatures (with context) and to use it in the theme of your choice. Not an easy task!